# get the List<Customer> to oracle database in index values

Tags: java

Please below to java source code, I have got address values from oracle database index.
But, this is index error code. I can't find the error.

```
public List<Customer> selByAddress(String address) {

    List<Customer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {

        String query = "select id, name, password, age, address from customer_tb where address = ? ";

        conn = factory.createConnection();
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);

        pstmt.setString(5, address);
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()) {
            Customer ct = new Customer();
            ct.setId(rs.getString("id"));
            ct.setPasswd(rs.getString("passwd"));
            ct.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            ct.setAge(rs.getInt("age"));
            ct.setAddress(rs.getString("address"));

            list.add(ct);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        JdbcUtils.closeResource(conn, pstmt, rs);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: but what is the problem? do you get an exception? empty result?

Comment: it's error code.
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index

Comment: Having `password` in one place and `passwd` in another also doesn't bode well for this program.

Comment: keep still,,,but, can not print to java address values.

Comment: i have changed syntax (password to passw).
can not check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need to study a bit more about Prepare Statement. You have problem with below code:

```
pstmt.setString(5, address);
```

While you query has just one wildcard (?) - you are trying to set string to the 5th one (which doesn't exists). Change it to:

```
pstmt.setString(1, address);
```